# Is there a way to null-annotate this return value (not null depending on arguments) or do I need to redesign?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

This API definition predates nullability annotations. Is there a way to annotate this correctly or do I need to redesign the API surface?

```
    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> GetDirectoryContents(string path,
        NonExtantDirectoryBehavior nonExtantDirectoryBehavior = NonExtantDirectoryBehavior.Throw,
        FollowSymbolicLinks followSymbolicLinks = FollowSymbolicLinks.Never)
```

`nonExtantDirectoryBehavior` will always be a constant in the caller; `GetDirectoryContents` can only return null if the argument's value is `ReturnNull`.

I have to actually place the attributes rather than use ?, but that's a minor detail.

Comment: If nothing else, use the `<returns>` element in XML comments. That's been used since the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GetDirectoryContents can only return null if the argument's value is ReturnNull.

The [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MaybeNullWhenAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.maybenullwhenattribute?view=net-6.0) is the closest you could get to that behavior, but it takes a boolean argument.

If you were willing to revise the method signature to make that parameter a boolean or use a separate named method (e.g. `TryGetDirectoryContents`), you could probably get that kind of behavior. Otherwise, you could just note that the return value can be null in general, or leave it how it is.